# How to add a custom post type in child theme? (Wordpress > 3.0)

Tags: custom-post-types, child-theme

I'm using Wordpress Magazine Style Theme (http://wordpress.org/themes/magazine-style) which doesn't have any other than default post format set (no galleries, aside, etc.).

I would like to create a child theme that would have custom post types added via register_post_type() function.

In **childtheme** folder I created files:

- style.css with import rule
- functions.php

According to Codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) I've added in **functions.php**:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'acme_product',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
?>
```

But I can't see the new Product post type while creating a new post (there is no "Format" menu).

What else I have to do to enable custom post types in child theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new CPT adds a dedicated *admin menu* for managing posts of that type, not a new post format. Those are two different concepts, post format is used to add some meta information on the content of a single post while CPTs are used to create different classes of posts.

Comment: Could be worth mentioning that post formats cannot be removed or added by plugins or themes.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats

Comment: @AndrewBartel, why don't you make an answer out of that info? I was just trying to make mine be more then one sentence....

Comment: I feel you answered the question just fine, the main point imo was that the two were totally different concepts, I just wanted to add to it in case the OP was hoping to manage the formats.